# Error implicitly converting List<T> to CustomList<T> using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

How to convert `List` to `List<T>`?

```
 var memberCommunicationPreferenceses = new PersonifyCollection<MemberCommunicationPreferences>();

memberCommunicationPreferenceses = (from ICustomerOptIn customerOptIn in customerData.CustomerOptIns
        select new Models.MemberCommunicationPreferences()
       {
         MemberCommunicationsPrefernceId = customerOptIn.CustomerOptInId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
         ShortName = customerOptIn.OptionShortNameString,
         ShortNameDescription = customerOptIn.OptionShortName.Description
         .....
       }).Where(x=>x.OptedInFlag).ToList();
```

### error

```
Error   23  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EBusiness.Model.Models.MemberCommunicationPreferences>' 
 to 'EBusiness.Model.Models.Collections.PersonifyCollection<.EBusiness.Model.
  Models.MemberCommunicationPreferences>'   C:\\Trunk\Source\EBusiness\EBusiness.Model\Concrete\Personify\
     PersonifyMemberCommunicationPreferences.cs 94  31  EBusiness.Model
```

update:

--

PersonifyCollection of code based on the 2nd answer in this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176416/implementing-ilist-interface)

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match your code and the error message... You probably meant "Converting List<T> to PersonifyCollection<T>"

Comment: Anyway, we can't answer this question, because PersonifyCollection seems to be a class in your own code...

Comment: Yes,  ` public class PersonifyCollection<T> : IList<T>    { }`

Comment: does it have a constructor that accepts an IEnumerable<T> ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371174/linq-with-custom-base-collection

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what methods your `PersonifyCollection` class has, so we can't tell you how to convert to it, or if it has any methods to do so.  You could try:

```
var something=new PersonifyCollection<MemberCommunicationPreferences>(memberCommunicationPreferences);
```

If your custom collection implements the standard constructor that takes an IEnumerable, that should work.